# How to align off viewport DIV perfectly adjacent to visible viewport DIV

Tags: html, jquery, css, alignment

I am working on a project that would slide out one div and slide in another from off-screen depending on the click of two buttons. All is working and functioning as needed except that I need the two DIVs to align side by side.  The off-viewport div always aligns underneath the in-viewport DIV.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".tow").click(function() {
    if ($(".ctow").hasClass("nodisplay")) {
      $(".ctow").removeClass("nodisplay");
      $(".ctoc").addClass("nodisplay");
      $(".ctoc").removeClass("active");
      $(".tow").addClass("selected");
      $(".toc").removeClass("selected");
    }
  });

  $(".toc").click(function() {
    if ($(".ctoc").hasClass("nodisplay")) {
      $(".ctoc").addClass("active");
      $(".ctoc").removeClass("nodisplay");
      $(".ctow").addClass("nodisplay");
      $(".tow").removeClass("selected");
      $(".toc").addClass("selected");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Flexbox Responsive Off-Canvas Layout */

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav a {
  margin: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.ctow {
  background-color: darkorange;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(0%);
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 50px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}

.ctoc {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(100%);
  padding: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}

.ctow.nodisplay {
  transform: translate(-100%);
}

.ctoc.nodisplay {
  transform: translate(100%);
}

.ctoc.active {
  transform: translate(0%);
}

#footer {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0;
}


/** 1 PANEL **/

#right,
#left {
  display: none;
}


/** 2 PANELS (-R) **/

@media (min-width: 41em) {
  #left {
    display: box;
  }
}


/** 3 PANELS **/

@media (min-width: 61em) {
  #right,
  #left {
    display: box;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav"><a href="#" class="tow">Left Div</a>
  <a href="#" class="toc">Right Div</a>
</div><br />
<span style="color:red;">Sample Viewport<br /><br /></span>
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="ctow">TOW Div Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </div>
  <div class="ctoc nodisplay">TOC Div</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kbosu31/pen/XWorELV) of my issue.

I've tried using css floats, display: table-cell; etc.  Cannot use absolute positioning or fixed positioning in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating your styles to make the wrapper display flex. Not really sure exactly how you want it to look but this should make the divs display side by side. I've also updated your transform values to make the divs slide next to each other.

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.ctow {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: darkorange;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(0%);
  padding: 50px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}

.ctoc {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(100%);
  padding: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}

.ctoc.nodisplay {
  transform: translate(100%);
}

.ctoc.active {
  transform: translate(-100%);
}
```